# Show local images inside WebView windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, html, resources, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to load a html file in Webview in WP8.1 app. I have the image stored inside my project. When I run the html file in browser it runs properly but when I load this html file in Webview it does not show image and same thing happens when I convert the contents of HTML file in string and try the NavigateToString method. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title></title>
      <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 0px;
        }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <img src="ms-appx:///discount_icon.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="400" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        <div align="Left" style="width: 100%;">
                            <div style="width: 70%; float: left;"><b> Left </b>    </div>

                            <div align="right" style="width: 30%; float: right;">
                                <div align="right" style="position: relative;  padding-top:10px; background-image: url('ms-appx:///discount_icon.jpg');background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; height:36px; width: 85px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><span style="text-align:center;color:white; margin-right:27px;margin-top:15px">5%</span></div>
                            </div>

                            <div style="width: 70%; float: left;"> From <span style="background-color:#01A9DB;padding:2px;">$250.00</span> values </div>

                        </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>February</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Can I bother you to just test something that I wonder if it is the issue? Your `<meta`, `<img`, etc. tags, make them so that they aren't self closing i.e. `<meta ...> </meta>` and `<img.. ></img>`

Comment: These tags are closed properly and this is not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put `ms-appx:///` before the image name in the source of the html image.

If you have the image in the same folder of the html, the code would be like this:

`<img src="test.png" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can try *NavigateToLocalStreamUri*. You can google it. There are a lot of examples about that function.